Differential equation of monomials -- finding singularities
I have a 2-dimensional system of differential equations of the following form:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = x(t)^{a+b} y(t)^a
\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = x(t)^c y(t)^{c+d}
$$
(Some readers may recognize these as Cobb-Douglas functions from economics.)
Denote $Z$ the vector of $(x,y)$. Taking logs, we can write
$$
\ln \left( \frac{dZ}{dt} \right) = A \ln (Z(t))
$$
where the logs are taken element-wise and
$$
A = \left( \begin{array} aa+b & a \\ c & c+d \end{array} \right)
$$
I want to solve for the conditions under which $Z$ has a singularity. I am observing the following numerically, but am unable to justify it:

Suppose $b,d<1$ and $0<a,c<1$. Then: If the biggest eigenvalue of $A$ is greater than 1, $Z$ has a singularity.
(And if the parameter restrictions are not in place, then the eigenvalue condition is neither necessary nor sufficient for a singularity)

Any thoughts on why this would be true? The system is a nonlinear differential equation; it's not obvious to me why the eigenvalues would tell us anything (global) about the system, let alone what's going on with the parameter restrictions.

Please elaborate how you arrive at $$\ln \left( \frac{dZ}{dt} \right) = A \ln (Z(t))$$

If you just take logs of both sides of the system -- where to be clear Z is a vector. Is my notation non-standard?

Ok, I got confused by the prime sign that you use for transposition.

The word singularity might be overloaded, but you mean "running away to infinity in finite positive time regardless what initial conditions $x_0>0, y_0>0$ are chosen", right?

No, then it would be a linear system in $\ln Z.$ I think you suffered from the same confusion: the prime sign does not mean derivative, but transpose.

@Lieven, thank you and apologies, yes! The prime sign is for transposition

@Yves, thanks, I indeed mean to have $log (dZ/dt)$. By singularity, I mean that for a finite $T$, we have $\lim_{t\to T} Z(t) = \infty$. Thanks again!

Solving for $y$ as a function of $x$ suggests that for generic $a,b,c$ and $d$ the flow curves satisfy $Ky^p=Lx^q+E$ where the real constants $K,L,p$ and $q$ depend on $a,b,c$ and $d$ and where $E$ is an integration constant. Inspired by the case $E=0$ let's look at any possible solutions of the form $x=\alpha t^r,$ $y=\beta t^s.$ Substituting them into the equations gives
$$\begin{align}
\alpha^{a+b-1}\beta^a&=r \\
\alpha^c\beta^{c+d-1}&=s \\
(a+b)r+as &=r-1 \\
cr+(c+d)s &=s-1 \\
\end{align}$$
We limit ourselves to the open first quadrant $x,y>0,$ while noting that it would be possible to consider the equations on the positive $X$ and $Y$ axis, too. Thus we only consider solutions where both $r$ and $s$ are positive.
The last two equations can be written in matrix form
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a+b-1 & a \\
c & c+d-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r \\
s \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This means that the matrix must be invertible and its inverse maps $(-1,-1)^T$ into the open first quadrant. We will show that, under the given constraints on $a,b,c,d,$ this is related to $A$ having no eigenvalue greater than $1$ as suggested by the OPs numerical experiments.
Observation 1
Let $a,c>0$ and let $b$ and $d$ be arbitrary real numbers. Then the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a+b-1 & a \\
c & c+d-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
has two distinct real eigenvalues.
Proof
The discriminant of the characteristic equation is
$(a+b-c-d)^2+4ac>0.$ //
Proposition 2
Let $a,c>0$ and let $b,d<1.$ If the determinant of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a+b-1 & a \\
c & c+d-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
is positive, then the diagonal elements are both negative; in particular the trace is negative and so are both of the eigenvalues.
Proof
The determinant being positive means that
$$ac<(a+b-1)(c+d-1).$$
In particular, the factors $a+b-1$ and $c+d-1$ of the RHS have the same sign.
By hypothesis, $b-1$ and $d-1$ are both negative numbers. If $a+b-1$ and $c+d-1$ were positive then the product of $a$ and $c$ would be less than the product of two smaller positive numbers, so $a+b-1$ and $c+d-1$ are both negative. The trace of the matrix is just their sum. The two eigenvalues have the same sign because their product is the (positive) determinant, and that sign must be negative because their sum is the trace. //
Proposition 3
Let $a,c>0$ and $b,d<1.$ If the equations have a solution of the proposed form in the upper right open quadrant, then the determinant of $A-1$ is positive.
Proof
We have
$$\begin{pmatrix}
r \\
s
\end{pmatrix}
=
D^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
c+d-1 & -a \\
-c & a+b-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$$
where
$$D=\det(A-1)=(a+b-1)(c+d-1)-ac.$$
If $D$ is positive (this is the case when $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues less than $1$) the conditions for $r$ and $s$ to be positive become
$a-c-d+1>0,$ $c-a-b+1>0$ or equivalently
$$d-1<a-c<1-b.$$ If the $D$ is negative those inequalities have to be reversed; but this would require $b+d-2>0$ which is exluded by the assumptions $b<1$ and $d<1.$ //
Corollary 4
Under the same hypotheses, $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues less than 1. //
The determinant itself is an inhomogeneous quadratic polynomial. So we end up with a quadratic semialgebraic set in the $4$-space of the parameters $a,b,c$ and $d.$
In fact, some of the above conditions for $r$ and $s$ to be positive are redundant because they can be concluded from the positivity of the determinant, and we have
Proposition 5
Let $a,c>0$ and let $b,d<1.$ If $(a+b-1)(c+d-1)-ac>0$ then the system of differential equations
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=x(t)^{a+b}y(t)^a \\
\frac{dy}{dt}&=x(t)^cy(t)^{c+d} \\
\end{align}$$
has a solution of the form $x=\alpha t^r,$ $y=\beta t^s$ with positive $\alpha,\beta,r$ and $s.$
Proof
We need to show that the unique solution $(r,s)$ from the linear system
$$\begin{pmatrix}
a+b-1 & a \\
c & c+d-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
r \\
s \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 \\
-1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has positive components. Since the determinant of the square matrix is positive, we know that this is equivalent to the conditions
$$\begin{align}
a-c-d+1&>0 \\
c-a-b+1&>0 \\
\end{align}$$
From proposition 2 we know that $-c-d+1$ and $-a-b+1$ are positive; adding a positive $a$ to the former and a positive $c$ to the latter will not change the sign. //
Conclusions
The hypotheses $a<1$ and $c<1$ are redundant. Under the hypotheses $a,c>0$ and $b,d<1$ the solvability of the system in terms of simple power expressions in $t$ is equivalent to $A$ having both eigenvalues strictly less than $1.$
General solution
Until here I have only considered solutions for one particular choice of the integration constant. Let's have a look at the case of arbitrary initial conditions in one logical direction, i.e., assuming that the determinant is positive and examining the existence of global solutions
To understand the role of the integration constant it helps to look at the one-dimensional case
$$x′=x(t)^p.$$
The general solution of that standalone ODE when $p\neq1$ is
$$x(t)=\left(t(1−p)+C\right)^{\frac1{1−p}}$$
(for $p=1$ the solution is an exponential).
For $p<1$ (corresponding to our determinant being positive) there is no problem: the solution exists for all sufficiently large positive $t$ no matter the value chosen for the constant $C.$ For $p>1$ the expression between brackets can be positive only if $C$ is, and then only up to time $t_0=C/(p−1).$ Just before that time we are taking a negative exponential of an increasingly small positive number, meaning the solution runs off to infinity in finite time.
Proposition 6
Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers such that $1-c-d+a\neq0$ and $1+c-a-b\neq0.$
Then the following system of nonlinear differential equations in the open first quadrant of the $XY$ plane, i.e., for $x>0$ and $y>0:$
$$\begin{align}
x'(t)=x(t)^{a+b}y(t)^a \\
y'(t)=x(t)^cy(t)^{c+d} \\
\end{align}$$
has a general solution satisfying
$$x'(t)=x^{a+b}\left(\frac{1-c-d+a}{1+c-a-b}x^{1+c-a-b}+E\right)^\frac{a}{1-c-d+a}\equiv F_{a,b,c,d,E}(x).$$
for any real constant $E$ whenever the expression between brackets is positive.
In particular, if $a>0,$ $c>0,$ $b<1,$ $d<1$ and $(a+b-1)(c+d-1)-ac>0$, there is a solution that extends to arbitrarily large $t.$
Proof
Dividing the second equation by the first gives
$$y(t)^{-c-d+a}y'(t)=x(t)^{c-a-b}x'(t)$$
which, under the hypotheses on $a,b,c,d,$ integrates to
$$\frac{y^{1-c-d+a}}{1-c-d+a}=\frac{x^{1+c-a-b}}{1+c-a-b} + E.$$
Solving this algebraically for $y$ and substituting the result into the first differential equation gives the desired form for $x'(t).$
If the additional conditions for $a,b,c,d$ are satisfied then we know from proposition 2 that $a+b-1$ and $c+d-1$ are both negative and therefore $1-c-d+a>0$ and $1+c-a-b>0.$ This means that the expression between brackets is dominated by the first term and even if $E$ is negative the expression will be positive for sufficiently large $x.$ Therefore there exists a constant $K>0$ and an $x_0>0,$ possibly depending on $a,b,c,d,E,$ such that for $x\geq x_0$
$$F_{a,b,c,d,E}(x)<Kx^{a+b+\frac{a(1+c-a-b)}{1-c-d+a}}.$$
It is easy to verify that the exponent is strictly less than $1$ if and only if $(a+b-1)(c+d-1)-ac>0.$ //
Note that in this general case I have only proven one implication: if the matrix has two eigenvalues less than $1,$ then the solution holds for all sufficiently large $t.$ The analysis for $(a+b-1)(c+d-1)-ac\leq0$ is complicated by the fact that we need to consider the signs of $1+c-a-b$ and $1-c-d+a$ separately.
If they are both still positive while the determinant is negative, most of the analysis of proposition 6 holds and the first term between brackets is still dominant. The solution then explodes because $x'(t)$ is eventually greater than some constant times $x(t)$ raised to a power greater than $1.$
We can exclude the special case $E=0$ because it is covered by proposition 3.
If $1-c-d+a$ and $1+c-a-b$ are both negative it is the $E$ term that dominates the expression between brackets. If $E<0$ the expression becomes $0$ in finite time, and we are raising it to a negative power. If $E>0$ the derivative $x'(t)$ is then asymptotically proportional to $x^{a+b}.$ From the hypothesis $1+c-a-b<0$ and the assumption $c>0$ we conclude $a+b>1,$ implying that $x$ explodes in this case, too.
If $1-c-d+a>0$ and $1+c-a-b<0$ then the $E$ term dominates the other (this time negative) term and $x'(t)$ is asymptotically proportional to $x^{a+b}$ with $a+b>1.$
If $1-c-d+a<0$ and $1+c-a-b>0$ then the expression between brackets is dominated by a negative term involving a positive power of $x$ and we are raising it to a negative power.
Thus, if the determinant is negative, in each of the four cases determined by the signs of $1-c-d+a$ and $1+c-a-b,$ regardless what integration constant $E$ we choose there is no solution for $x(t)$ that extends to arbitrarily large $t>0.$
Further exploration: explicit solution for the "singular" case
If $\det(A-1)<0$ then the flow curves for $y$ as a function of $x$ still make sense; I think that they might be satisfied by a solution that becomes degenerate at $t=K$ (where $K$ is an arbitrary positive constant) of the form
$$x=\alpha(K-t)^{-r},y=\beta(K-t)^{-s}.$$

This is extremely useful, thank you!!! I'm still working through the proofs. You have $r,s>0$ -- am I correct to say that this implies there are no singularities when $E=0$, for all finite $t$? So your comments in "further explorations" are necessary to prove the conjecture in the OP? Thank you!

I confirm that there are no singularities for $E=0$ in the sense that $x$ and $y$ remain finite for all positive $t.$

Your question mentioned the occurrence of singularities in numerical experiments, but did not elaborate on initial conditions. My answer proves that if the determinant is positive, there exists at least one solution that does not exhibit such singular behaviour. The further exploration is about proving that under the same positivity condition, all solutions remain regular.

To understand the role of the integration constant it helps to look at the one-dimensional case $x'=x(t)^p.$ The general solution is $x(t)=(t(1-p)+C)^{1/(1-p)}.$ For $p<1$ (corresponding to our determinant being positive) there is no problem, the solution exists for all large positive $t$ no matter what the constant. For $p>1$ the expression between brackets can be positive only if $C$ is, and then only up to time $t_0=C/(p-1).$ Just before that time we are taking a negative exponential of an increasingly small positive number, meaning the solution runs off to infinity in finite time.

Or did you want to consider large negative times as well? Because in that case my whole answer breaks down and I suspect there are are no solutions extending across the whole time axis left and right.

I have added the analysis for general integration constant $E$ (implying general initial conditions). As we suspected the conclusion remains the same as for $E=0$ even if there is no guaranteed closed form for the solution.
